# Sql do an insert then throw exception

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
THEN 
    INSERT INTO queuedcourses(idnumber, code) VALUES (new.idnumber, new.code);
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Course % is full, you are put in the waiting list', new.code;
    END IF;

END IF;

INSERT INTO registratedcourses(idNumber, code) VALUES (new.idnumber, new.code);
RAISE NOTICE 'You are now successfully registered to course %', new.code; 
RETURN NULL;
```

For some reason the insert is skipped. Is it not possible to do an insert and then a exception?

Comment: There are two insert statement, which one are you referring at?

Comment: Why are you wanting to throw an exception? I don't understand the reasoning for raising an error just to display an informative message.

Comment: Why do you want to raise an exception? Exceptions should be used when your application is acting as expected. Adding someone to the waiting list is expected when the course is full. It's not an error, it's part of the expected behavior.

Comment: The last insert is the one the trigger wants to achieve.

Comment: Show the complete source of your stored function

Comment: registratedcourses is the correct insertion, the other is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you raise an exception then whole transaction will rollback and no data will be stored in database. It's not clear why do use exception. Do you want to prevent insertion on table by trigger? If so then you should return `NULL` instead of throwing an exception. Otherwise return `NEW` at the end of trigger.